# CodeIgniter version Upgration

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to upgrade Code igniter version 1.7 to 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you don't need to upgrade through each version, one by one. Just read all the [instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) to upgrade between your version and the target one, and build a list of things to do, then you can execute that list on one go. Here are some of the things that I added to my list when upgrading from 1.7.2 to 3.1.3.

Add `return parent::__get($prop);` to your `_get` magic methods (if you have them).

Replace `$this->validation->error_string` with `validation_errors()`

Replace in views $this->validation->field_name with set_value(‘field_name’) and set_select(), etc.. And add the value to be used to pre-populate each field. But take in account that set_value() does not work if you don’t run form_validation->run() first.

When retrieving data: Replace `$this->validation->field_name` and `$this->form_validation->field_name` with `$this->input->post(‘field_name’)`

When setting data: Replace `$this->form_validation->field_name` with `$this->form_validation->set_data($data);`

Take in account that `set_data($other_data)` overwrites the content of `$_POST`, so you need to merge $other_data and `$_POST`.

Good luck, and just power through it!.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just read this [Guide to Upgrade from CI 1.7 to lastest](http://burnignorance.com/php-programming-tips/upgrading-a-codeigniter-application-1-7-0-or-older-to-latest-version-of-codeigniter/). That will help you to upgrading the CodeIgniter. Was tried on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is huge up-gradation in CI framework it self so its better that you should go step by step.

- Take your backup of code (Helper, Controller, Model, Views)
- Database

Then you need to check both version's release notes and you need to up-grade core.

Maybe you need to reduce your own code as in 1.7 you wrote and in 3.x its already in their core

then you need to integrate your written code and write the test cases.

Then run the test cases.

I think its not a one step or one day task :)